# How to combine two (or morer) DF w/ different leng and ind providing an appropriate index for both in a single DF

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, concatenation

I have two dataframes (DF and DF2). **Anyobody could help me in understand how can I combine these two dataframes and make them look like this third one (DF3)?** I presented a simple example, but I need this to compile dataframes that include different samples (or observations). Eventually, there are samples that emcompass the same group of variables. But most of the cases, the samples present different variables. Each column corresponds to one sample.

Any help is welcome!

DF -

```
raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
        'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze'],
        'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73],
        'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
        'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
print(df)
```

DF2 -

```
raw_data2 = {'first_name': ['Molly', 'Jake'],
             'civil_status': ['Single', 'Single']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data2, columns = ['first_name', 'civil_status'])
print(df2)´´´
```

DF3 -

```
raw_data3 = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
        'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze'],
        'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73],
        'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
        'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70],
             'civil_status': ['NaN', 'Single', 'NaN', 'Single', 'NaN']}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data3, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore',
                                         'civil_status'])
print(df3)
```

Comment: did you try `pd.concat`?

Answer (score 0):

[join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

```
df.set_index("first_name").join(df2.set_index("first_name"))
```

Comment: In fact, it did not solve the whole problem. When a dataframe containing more variables (lines) is joined to the first, it simply delete the new variables.

Answer (score 0):

I applied the solution above in the real context, by using the code below:

```
arquivo1 = pd.read_excel(f1, header=7, index_col=False)

arquivo2 = pd.read_excel(f2, header=7, index_col=False)

joined = arquivo1.set_index("Element").join(arquivo2.set_index("Element"))
```

It provided ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['AN', 'series', ' Net', ' [wt.%]', ' [norm. wt.%]', '[norm. at.%]',
'Error in %'],
dtype='object')

The pictures below represent "arquivo1" and "arquivo2"

[arquivo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwNSl.png)

[arquivo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BIKJ.png)

When I include the suffix 'Element' in the right and left, it actually join the both dataframe.

```
joined = arquivo1.set_index("Element").join(arquivo2.set_index("Element"), lsuffix='Element', rsuffix='Element')
```

But when a dataframe containing more variables (lines) is joined to the first, it simply delete the new variables. Anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: make **rsuffix** and **lsuffix** different so that column names don't overlap